# Cannot find certain implementing classes in Android

Tags: android

In short, I am looking for the implementation of the IAlarmManager.

I am interested in the scheduling done by the AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating method and so I started looking for the implementation but I haven't been able to find anything.  Internally to AlarmManager, I can see that the actual work is being done by an android.app.IAlarmManager interface.  After googling around for a bit there seems to reference to an implementing class called android.app.IAlarmManager.Stub but that is as far I get.
I am working with Android 1.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IAlarmManager` is AIDL interface - used for RPC calls to remote `Service`.

The `IAlarmManager.Stub` is nested static class, used for obtaining and referencing the remote service - the `Service` you'll be exposing through the interface will extend the *.Stub class.
For more info on using AIDL look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html

The concrete service that you are looking for is called `AlarmManagerService`. You can find its source code and the implementation of `setInexactRepeating()` here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/services/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java
Hope that helps.

Comment: As of Android 4.4.2, the AIDL documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) and the implementation of `setInexactRepeating()` is [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/AlarmManager.java). The implementation of `IAlarmManager` in `AlarmManager` is [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java).